# Bisect keep indexes of inserted items

Tags: python, sorting, bisection

I am using the bisect module to keep a list sorted while inserting numbers.
Lets say I have am going to insert three numbers `9, 2, 5` in this order.
The last state of this list would be obviously `[2, 5, 9]`, however, is there any chance that I can find the index list that numbers are inserted into this list. For this list it would be `[1, 2, 0]`. So the list I need is the indexes [0, 1, 2] after the sort is happened which in bisect is in happening with each insertion, thats why I could not find a way. I could just sort it with `key` feature of the `sorted` function however I dont want to increase the complexity. So my question is this achievable with the bisect module ?

Here is the code I use,

```
import bisect

lst = []

bisect.insort(lst, 9)
bisect.insort(lst, 2)
bisect.insort(lst, 5)

print lst
```

**Edit:** Another example would be, i am going to insert the numbers 4, 7, 1, 2, 9 to some empty list. (Let's first assume without bisect, that I already have the numbers in the list)

```
[4, 7, 1, 2, 9]
# indexes [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], typical enumeration
```

after sorting,

```
[1, 2, 4, 7, 9]
# now the index list [2, 3, 0, 1, 4]
```

Can it be done with bisect without increasing complexity.

**Note:** The order of the insertion is not arbitrary. It is known, thats why I try to use indexes with bisect.

Comment: What? I don't understand what you mean. Given that each insertion could change the position of an element, what you are describing doesn't exist. You have to define what index you want for each insertion. Do you want the sequence of indeces at which the value was inserted? Then this would be `0` (number `9` was inserted at index `0`), `0` (number `2` was inserted at position `0`) and `1` (number `5` was inserted at position `1`). If this isn't what you mean please try to explain better what you want exactly, maybe with a slightly bigger example (say 5 elements, instead of 3).

Comment: @Bakuriu The indexes are actually the indexes of the unsorted list. I need the indexes sorted using the values in the real list, not the index list. I am trying to achieve this with bisect.

Answer (score 0):

`insort` has no idea in what order the items were inserted. You'll have to add that logic yourself. One way to do so could be to insert 2-tuples consisting of the value and the index:

```
bisect.insort(lst, (9, 0))
bisect.insort(lst, (2, 1))
bisect.insort(lst, (5, 2))
```

You would need to keep track of the index yourself as you're adding objects, but as sequences are sorted first by the first item, then by the next, etc., this will still sort properly without any extra effort.

Comment: Does tuples sorted using the left-most elements ? (I mean a list of tuples of course)

Comment: @MaxPythone Yes, that's the meaning of the last sentence.